# Parsing json in PHP returning blank

Tags: php, ajax, json, facebook

I am sending a JSON string (correctly recieved from the facebook api) to PHP using ajax.  When I try and parse the JSON string it adds extra characters to the string and when I try and obtain a value from the string I get nothing.

Here is the json as returned from facebook:

```
{"id":"redacted","email":"redacted","first_name":"redacted","gender":"female","last_name":"redacted","link":"redacted","locale":"en_US","name":"redacted","timezone":-6,"updated_time":"2014-12-17T23:10:00+0000","verified":true}
```

Here is the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "signupfacebookajax.php",
                       data: { theresponse: JSON.stringify(response) },
                       success: function(crap){ console.log(crap)}
                       });
                });
```

Here is the code on the php page signupfacebookajax.php:

```
$response = $_POST['theresponse'];
$jsondecode = json_decode($response);
$facebook_id = $jsondecode->id;
echo $facebook_id;
```

Noting is returned at all.  While troubleshooting I noticed that the JSON string looks odd after decoding it.  Here is what I get after decoding the string after passed by ajax.

```
{\"id\":\"redacted\",\"email\":\"redacted\",\"first_name\":\"redacted\",\"gender\":\"female\",\"last_name\":\"redacted\",\"link\":\"redacted\",\"locale\":\"en_US\",\"name\":\"redacted\",\"timezone\":-6,\"updated_time\":\"2014-12-17T23:10:00+0000\",\"verified\":true}
```

Comment: Is that output $response, or $jsondecode?

Comment: $response is the string sent by ajax, $jsondecode is decoding that string.  $facebook_id is the id from the json string after it has been decoded which shows nothing. not sure how or where its going on

Comment: Well I was able to decode without any issue: both the response from Facebook and the one with all the \.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling magic quotes??? It looks like your php.ini has

```
magic_quotes_gpc = On
```

for more read [Disable Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

To disable it just replace On with Off

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```